# How to obtain this formula for 2+1 dimensional boosts

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lorentz-symmetry, anyons

In [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.43.1933) on anyons, a formula for boost transformations in 2+1 dimensional spacetime is given (equations 2.7--2.10).
The boost transformation here is defined as:
$$\displaystyle B(p) \hat{p} = p$$

where $\hat{p}$ is the rest frame momentum = $(m,0,0)$.

The formula for $B(p)$ is then given to be:

$$\displaystyle B(p) = e^{i \Omega_a(p)J^a} $$

where $J^a$ are representations of the generators of so(2,1), given by ${(J^b)}_{ac}= i{{\epsilon_a}^b}_c$. (The so(2,1) algebra is $[J^a,J^b]=i\epsilon^{abc}J_c$.)

$\Omega_a(p)$ is given by:
$$\displaystyle \Omega_a(p) = \epsilon_{abc} \frac{p^b}{|p|}\eta^c\ln \frac{E+|p|}{m} $$

where $\eta^a = (1,0,0)$ and $E= \sqrt{|p|^2 +m^2}$.

I want to understand how to derive or understand this formula for the boost generator.

Comment: Shouldn't the epsilon have an iota in front of it? In the definition of J I mean.

Comment: Already been asked - see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/344971/unitary-representations-of-the-poincare-group-in-21-dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To boost a vector $(m,0,0)$ to a general vector, $p$, one must do a Lorentz transformation in the direction of $p$. To determine the magnitude, check this Wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation, which gives the formula for a general Lorentz transformation:
$$L=\begin{bmatrix}\gamma&-\gamma\beta n_x&-\gamma\beta n_y\\\gamma\beta n_x&1+(\gamma-1)n^2_x&(\gamma-1)n_xn_y\\\gamma\beta n_y&1+(\gamma-1)n_xn_y&(\gamma-1)n_y^2\end{bmatrix}$$
I have suppressed the z index because it is a three dimensional problem. $\gamma$ turns out to be $(1+\dfrac{p^2}{m^2})^{1/2}$ and $\beta$ is $\frac{p}{(p^2+m^2)^{1/2}}$.

Now, it remains to be shown that $L=exp(i\Omega_a(p)J^a)$. Expanding out the argument of the exponential it becomes, $$exp(i\Omega_a(p)J^a)=exp[ln(\frac{E+p}{m})\begin{bmatrix}0&-p_x/p&-p_y/p\\p_x/p&0&0\\p_y/p&0&0\end{bmatrix}]$$. This matrix is equivalent to a rotation matrix corresponding to a rotation by an angle $\theta=ln(\frac{E+P}{m})$ about an axis $\hat{n}=(0,-p_y/p,p_x/p)$ which you can verify by checking page 5 of [this article](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph216/rotation_12.pdf).

Then using the form of the rotation matrix given there and substituting for
$\theta$ we get the answer.